# Why dont I have the modified dictionary in Robot, even though the Python keyword has modified the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, robotframework

Here is my Robot File (robot-dictionary-tests.robot)

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  Passing a dictionary object from Robot to Python and vice versa
Library        Utils.py

# To run:
# robot -L debug -d Results/  Tests/robot-dictionary-tests.robot


*** Keywords ***
Call Python To Modify The Dictionary
[arguments]  &{named}
modify dictionary   ${named}

*** Test Cases ***
Test Modifying Robot Dictionary in Python
    &{d} =          Create Dictionary       key=original
    &{expected} =   Create Dictionary       key=modified
    Call Python To Modify The Dictionary    &{d}
    Should Be Equal   ${d}      ${expected}
```

Here is my Utils.py:

```
from robot.api import logger

@keyword('modify dictionary')
def modify_dictionary(d):
   logger.debug(f'before modification, d: {d}')
   for key in d:
       d[key] = 'modified'
   logger.debug(f'after modification, d: {d}')
```

The Test Case *Test Modifying Robot Dictionary in Python* fails:
[image]

My Question

Why does the robot test fail even though I passed the dictionary d reference to @keyword('modify dictionary')?

Comment: Does def modify_dictionary(d) need to return the dictionary ?

Comment: I intentionally implemented **def modify_dictionary(d)** as it is; so as  to check if the python function would modify the d in place. Then on Robot side, i wanted to check if my d is indeed modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've suspected, the variables are by reference and thus changed. To my knowledge this has more to do with Python, then Robot Framework.

Passing a dictionary as an object should be done through ${VarName} and not &{VarName}. The documenation on [Dictionary Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dictionary-variable-syntax) explains this like:

> ...a Python dictionary or a dictionary-like object can be used as a
>   dictionary variable like &{EXAMPLE}. In practice this means that
>   individual items of the dictionary are passed as named arguments to
>   the keyword

In the below code for keyword `Call Python To Modify The Dictionary` I change the keyword argument `&{named}` to `${named}` and where the keyword is called `&{d}` to `${d}`.

```
*** Keywords ***
Call Python To Modify The Dictionary
    [arguments]  ${named}
    modify dictionary   ${named}

*** Test Cases ***
Test Modifying Robot Dictionary in Python
    &{d} =          Create Dictionary       key=original
    &{expected} =   Create Dictionary       key=modified
    Call Python To Modify The Dictionary    ${d}
    Should Be Equal   ${d}      ${expected}
```

Resulting in:

```
Suite Executor: Robot Framework 3.1.2 (Python 3.7.0 on win32)
==============================================================================
SO003                                                                         
==============================================================================
SO003.Test :: Passing a dictionary object from Robot to Python and vice versa 
==============================================================================
Test Modifying Robot Dictionary in Python                             | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SO003.Test :: Passing a dictionary object from Robot to Python and... | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
SO003                                                                 | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Comment: Acc.to your fix, I conclude the following. In Robot side, passing a variable with '$' sign (i.e. ${varName} ) means that we are passing the reference to the object down to the keyword. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the scope of the variable and the difference between $ and &.